# How to create a relationship between user and some content type?

Tags: users, entities

I am new to Drupal and I need to create a relationship between user and content type.

There is a content type called 'Property'. The user who creates a property page ​must specify either:

- I am an owner, OR
- I am a tenant.

And I need to show this relationship on the property detail page.

How can I achieve this?

**Note**: I want to keep record of this, it mean the property detail page would always shows the previous tenant and owner information. And later that I want to show the reviews of user under owner and tenant tabs.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want to keep record of this, it mean the property detail page would always shows the previous tenant and owner information. And later that I want to show the reviews of user under owner and tenant tabs.

- The initial question sounds simple but the added comment turns it
  into a fairly complicated site build which I believe is outside the
  scope of StackExchange questions. I'm just going to give the OP a brief overview of what I would do. Mods, feel free to edit or whatever you need to do.

---

So along with normal fields like images, locations etc., you need a place to store all of the information relating to each owner or tenant in each property.. The screenshot below gives a basic example of this.

[image: Basic Field Collection]

[Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) will let you store this information. You should have one field collection for owners and another for tenants. All reviews etc. of each person will have to be inside a field collection. Or reference a field collection using the module below.

[Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) will let you reference the people and vice versa. You'll use this a massive amount on a site like this for almost everything.

[Entity Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) + [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) should allow tenants / owners to create property and also add themselves to a property by creating field collections from form data. You don't want to give them the ability to change other people's data so forms are essential.

[Entity Reference Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) will be essential for pre-filling form data and then disabling or hiding fields. This way, people can't view the workings of your site and more importantly, add and edit whatever they like. (for a regular end-user anyway).

Etc. Etc. Etc.

Anyways, that should be enough for you to look at for a couple of months. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This really seems like a perfect usecase for the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. Just create 2 (non global) flags to be used for flagging content of type "Property" (only) with labels something like this:

- (flag 1): I am an owner
- (flag 2): I am a tenant

When configuring these flag(s), you can also attach fields to each of them. You can use those fields to have a use enter a start date and possibly also an end date (since you seem to also "*want to keep record (track?) of this*". However to be able to attach fields (actually for users to enter date for those fields), make sure to also be aware about (and do) what is described in [Attaching fields to flags](https://www.drupal.org/node/917576), i.e.:

> By default, Flags use the "JavaScript toggle" link-type. While this allows entities to be flagged without reloading the page, users cannot set any field values with the Flag. In order for users to set a Flag's field values, you must use the "Form" link type.
>
> Navigate to `Administration > Structure > Flags` page. Click the Edit link for the Flag. Scroll down to the Display Options box and select the Confirmation Form radio button.

To "*show this relationship on the property detail page*" (as in your question also), just create an appropriate views (using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module) about users who flagged a node, format it as a block, and display the block on a property page.

But wait, there is more: the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module has great integrations with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. So pretty sure you'll find additional cases where you'll want to take advantage of these integrations also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the ultimate goal but you could just create a new List field for the content type named "Author is" and set it's options to: Owner, Tenant.

Author/creator could then select suitable option and when Property page is viewed it shows the author's "status".

Comment: but I want to keep record of this, it mean the property detail page would always shows the previous tenant and owner information. And later that I want to show the reviews of user under owner and tenant tabs.